# I want to pass multiple bucket names from parameter section and allow them in iam resouce section in one go - cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a use case where.

I want to pass multiple bucket names from parameter section and grant them read only access to those buckets in resources.i am able to achieve when count is restricted but how to achieve when count is not defined.

```
"Parameters": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Description": "Select Bucket Names to Associate with the policy"
        },
"Resource": [{"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::","Fn::Select": ["0", {
                                            "Ref": "S3Bucket"
                                    }]]
                                }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? In your code, what is `"Resource"`? Is it a template parameter?

Comment: resource will be IAM resource ARN where i want to pass multiple values from parameters and my ima resources ARN should be able to take consume all of them dynamically..

looks when we have defined values count it is possible but when i am trying dynamically getting no luck there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant pass values dynamically as cloud-formation template doest have a concept of looping.

If you want to use CommaDelimitedList and passing e.g. 5 values from parameter you have to fetch same value count in template.

Fn::Select does not check for null values or if the index is out of bounds of the array. Both conditions will result in a stack error, so you should be certain that the index you choose is valid, and that the list contains non-null values.

Source - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html